# Dynamically adding controls to View from Controller

Tags: wpf, mvvm

In WPF, I am using the MVVM model.

I have a `View` with a `UniformGrid` and a `ViewModel` where I would like to add items to the `UniformGrid` how would I accomplish this without doing it in the code behind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `UniformGrid` is a `Panel`; it's intent is not what you are trying to accomplish. You can achieve what you are trying to do however by adjusting the default `ItemsPanelTemplate` within an `ItemsControl`.

```
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding PropertyNameOnViewModel}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <UniformGrid/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        </ItemsControl>
```

This will allow you to bind to your ViewModel property within the `ItemsControl` and the data will get represented visually within a `UniformGrid`.